# Html input file type click event only fires once

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, click

I want to allow user to only select one zip file. If not, I show an alert() with some msg and then re-open the file select dialog window. I'm not able to programmatically open the file select window a second time by triggering the "click" event on the input element a second time. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/hanislovingit/40fcdtq8/

```js
        var MAX_FILE_SIZE = 300 * 1024 * 1024; // 300 MB
        var ZIP_FILE_TYPE = "application/x-zip-compressed";

        var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
          fileInputElem = document.getElementById("fileInputElem");

        fileInputElem.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

        fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          if (fileInputElem) {
            fileInputElem.click();
          }

          e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
        }, false);


        function handleFiles() {

          if (this.files.length > 1) {
            window.alert("Only one file may be uploaded at a time.");
            fileInputElem.click();

          } else {
            var file = this.files[0];

            if (file.type !== ZIP_FILE_TYPE) {
              window.alert("File(s) must be zipped before uploading. Please zip files and try again. File type is " + file.type);
              fileInputElem.click();
            }

            if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
              window.alert("The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be uploaded: " + file.size);
            }
          }

        }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInputElem" multiple style="display: none;" />
<a href="#" id="fileSelect">BROWSE FILES</a>
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine for me..In which browser are you testing..In chrome its working fine..

Comment: I've tested the fiddle in Chrome, Firefox, and MS Edge. It opened the file select window every time I tried, even after getting the alert about multiple files.

Comment: I'm not sure if you quite understood my question. I want the file select window to open by itself after the user had selected invalid file(s) and getting the alert popup, and after clicking on "ok" in the alert popup.